How to query from a joined table in SQLAlchemy
I have 2 tables with a many-to-many relationship, so I have a join table between them.  They are defined like this
from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column, relationship

from root.db.ModelBase import ModelBase


class Module(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'module'
    pk = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = mapped_column(String)
    is_active = mapped_column(Boolean)
    name = mapped_column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    ngen_cal_active = mapped_column(String)
    groups = relationship("ModuleGroup", secondary="module_group_member", back_populates="modules", lazy="joined")
---

from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column, relationship

from root.db.ModelBase import ModelBase


class ModuleGroup(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'module_group'
    pk = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = mapped_column(String)
    is_active = mapped_column(Boolean)
    name = mapped_column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    modules = relationship("Module", secondary="module_group_member", back_populates="groups", lazy="joined")
---

from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, Boolean, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column

from root.db.ModelBase import ModelBase


class ModuleGroupMember(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'module_group_member'
    description = mapped_column(String)
    is_active = mapped_column(Boolean)
    module_pk = mapped_column(ForeignKey('module.pk'), primary_key=True,)
    module_group_pk = mapped_column(ForeignKey('module_group.pk'), primary_key=True)

If I query like this
query = select(Module).where(Module.name == 'Module3')  # type: ignore
results = session.execute(query).unique().all()
print('results', results)

It appears to work (although I don't know why it forces me to use unique() since there should only be 1 result)
In the result, I see a groups object, which is defined by the relationship, so it all works fine.
However, if I want to get just the name and the associated groups, I tried something like this:
query = select(Module.name, Module.groups).where(Module.name == 'Module3') # type: ignore

and I get this error SAWarning: SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM element(s) "module_group", "module_group_member_1" and FROM element "module".  Apply join condition(s) between each element to resolve.
I'm not sure what the problem is.  I thought that SQLAlchemy would take care of any JOINS that need to be done
What I really want to do is get all the names and groups for every module
query = select(Module.name, Module.groups)



What I really want to do is get all the names and groups for every module

Rather than construct your own query, you can use a simple ORM query with load_only() to only retrieve Module.name, and eager-load the groups as usual.
    query = select(Module).options(load_only(Module.name))
    results = sess.scalars(query).unique().all()
    """
SELECT module.pk, module.name, module_group_1.pk AS pk_1, module_group_1.name AS name_1 
FROM module 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        module_group_member AS module_group_member_1 
        JOIN module_group AS module_group_1 
        ON module_group_1.pk = module_group_member_1.module_group_pk
    ) ON module.pk = module_group_member_1.module_pk
    """
    pprint(results)
    """
[Module(name=Module1, groups=[ModuleGroup(name=Group11), ModuleGroup(name=Group12)]),
 Module(name=Module3, groups=[ModuleGroup(name=Group31), ModuleGroup(name=Group32)])]
     """

You can then pull Module.name out as a scalar (str) value
    list_of_tuples = [(mod.name, mod.groups) for mod in results]
    pprint(list_of_tuples)
    """
[('Module1', [ModuleGroup(name=Group11), ModuleGroup(name=Group12)]),
 ('Module3', [ModuleGroup(name=Group31), ModuleGroup(name=Group32)])]
    """


Thanks.  This works, but can you explain it?  Is load_only the accepted way to query individual columns, instead of in the select?  And why does it force me to add unique()?

"Is load_only the accepted way to query individual columns, instead of in the select?" - No, select(Module.name, Module.description, …) is quite common, but it does have the effect of changing the query from retrieving ORM objects to retrieving ORM attributes (columns), making it act more like a SQLAlchemy Core query. As you have seen, one of the side-effects is that we don't get some of the "magic" like auto-joins via relationships.

"why does it force me to add unique()" - The full error message is "The unique() method must be invoked on this Result, as it contains results that include joined eager loads against collections". I assume that .unique() is what combines the multiple rows from the JOIN query — (parent1, child1), (parent1, child2) - into a single "row" for that parent which contains a collection of its child objects.
